# Java heap space error when save json file

Tags: java, filewriter, json-simple

I get this error: "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space", when save a big jsonObject on file with FileWriter

My code:

```
FileWriter  file2 = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\....\\test.json");
file2.write(jsonObject.toString());
file2.close();
```

My pom

```
<groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
<artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Would greatly appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `toString()` you're creating a string object first, before writing it to the `FileWriter`, which consumes a lot of memory for large objects. You should use `JSONObject.writeJSONString(Writer)` to reduce the memory footprint:

```
final JSONObject obj = ...
    
try (final Writer writer = new FileWriter(new File("output"))) {
    obj.writeJSONString(writer);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    // handle exception
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error) answer helps you to solve your issue. It could be possible that your JVM does not have enough (free) memory. Another solution could be to split a large JSON object into many smaller ones.